# Accidently send funds to non-hardware wallet (GUI desktop). Would like to move them to hardware wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, hardware-wallet, hardware

I purchased some monero and successfully sent my funds to my GUI desktop wallet. Stupidly, I created the hardware wallet account on the GUI desktop AFTER I had already sent the funds to my "regular" GUI wallet. It seems as if it is possible to essentially send the funds "to myself" via transaction from non-hardware wallet account to my hardware wallet account. Am I correct in utilizing a transaction in this way to secure the funds on my hardware?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems as if it is possible to essentially send the funds "to myself" via transaction from non-hardware wallet account to my hardware wallet account. Am I correct in utilizing a transaction in this way to secure the funds on my hardware?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Different wallets are like different "accounts" in that you can transfer them around as if they are separate people sending transactions to each other.

Comment: This is not quite true. "accounts" are a wallet level feature to group addresses in a wallet. A wallet can have many accounts. Sending from a hardware wallet to a non-hardware wallet are what the user needs to do.